# How to remove elements from a vector in a fast way in Clojure?

Tags: optimization, data-structures, collections, clojure

I'm trying to remove elements from a Clojure vector:

> Note that I'm using Clojure's operations from Kotlin

```
val set = PersistentHashSet.create("foo")
val vec = PersistentVector.create("foo", "bar")
val seq = clojure.`core$remove`.invokeStatic(set, vec) as ISeq
val resultVec = clojure.`core$vec`.invokeStatic(seq) as PersistentVector
```

This is the equivalent of the following Clojure code:

```
(remove #{"foo"} ["foo" "bar"])
```

The code works fine but I've noticed that creating a vector from the seq is extrmely slow. I've written a benchmark and these were the results:

```
| Item count | Remove ms | Remove with converting back to vector ms|
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| 1000       | 51        | 1355                                 |
| 10000      | 71        | 5123                                 |
```

Do you know how I can convert the `seq` resulting from the `remove` operation back to a `vector` without the harsh performance penalty?

If it is not possible is there an alternative way to perform the `remove` operation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try the complementary operation to `remove` that returns a vector:

```
(filterv (complement #{"foo"}) 
         ["foo" "bar"])
```

Note the use of `filterv`. The `v` indicates that it uses a vector from the start, and returns a vector, so no conversion is required. It uses a `transient` vector behind the scenes, so it should be pretty fast.

I'm negating the predicate using [`complement`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/complement) so I can use `filterv`, since there is no `removev`. [`remove` is just defined as the `complement` of `filter` anyway though](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2818), so it's basically what you were already doing, just strict.

Comment: This is faster but not dramatically: ~270ns vs. ~375ns for `remove` then `vec`. And yes `filterv` uses a transient vector, building it up using `reduce`.

Comment: @TaylorWood Thanks. Wasn't expecting anything monumental, but this was all I could think of.

Comment: To add to this - you could write custom code using transients that was more purpose-built to your removal case. But that's generally understood to be an un-necessary optimization unless it's really critical.

Comment: @Venantius Ya, I've only explicitly used `transient` a handful of times. One use case that comes to mind is if I have a complicated reduction that needs multiple accumulators, I'll switch it to a full `loop`, which I find to be much neater in some cases. Using a `transient` and `conj!` there has proven to be faster, but that use case doesn't come up frequently.

Comment: Not perfect, but still better than the original solution, thanks!

Comment: @AdamArold Not perfect, no. I suspect though that using only high-level constructs, this is about as good as you're going to get. You'll probably need to start hand-rolling something to get better results, or start reaching for mutable Java classes.

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to do fundamentally performs badly. Vectors are for fast indexed read/write, and O(1) access to the right end. To do anything else you must tear the vector apart and rebuild it again, an O(N) operation. If you need an operation like this to be efficient, you must use a different data structure.

Comment: What data structure do you suggest? I've seen `PersistentList` which I guess is the bakend for the `()` syntax but I don't know how it performs. Should I try that?

Comment: @AdamArold I think we may need a broader view if what you're trying to do. What are you doing with the filtered collection? If you're just filtering and mapping it, just sticking with the lazy-seq returned may be your best option. Or use transducers.

Comment: I'm working on a library (Java) which wraps Clojure's persistent collections and makes them accessible for Java users (adds functions and interfaces which blend into the JCF).

Comment: @AdamArold You can't find a single data structure that does everything. The reason Clojure's data structures support the operations that they do is that those are the operations that can perform well. Stuff you add to "blend in" will be stuff that performs badly.

Comment: I mean `LinkedList` gives you good `remove` performance characteristics but I don't know whether there is a Clojure equivalent for that.

Comment: What a perfect example! For LinkedList, remove of an arbitrary index is O(N), just as bad as Clojure's performance with a vector. This demonstrates perfectly what I said: there's no data structure that does everything well.

Comment: I think @AdamArold may be thinking of LinkedList's removal performance if you already have a reference to the node. But that's not obviously applicable from the original question, so I have to agree with amalloy. Clojure vectors are array-like data structures, and unless you know the index at which the element exists removal is going to be O(n).

Comment: @Venantius Even if you *do* know the element's index it's still O(N) time to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a PersistentHashSet? Fast removal, though not ordered. I do vaguely recall Clojure also having a sorted set in case that’s needed.

Comment: It does not adhere to the List contract: no duplicates allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You have made an error of accepting the lazy result of `remove` as equivalent to the concrete result of converting back to a vector.  Compare the lazy result of `(remove ...)` with the concrete result implied by `(count (remove ...))`.  You will see that it is slightly slower than just doing `(vec (remove ...))`.    Also, for real speed-critical applications, there is nothing like using a native Java `ArrayList`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require
    [criterium.core :as crit]    )
  (:import [java.util ArrayList]))

(def N 1000)
(def tgt-item (/ N 2))

(def pred-set #{ (long tgt-item) })
(def data-vec (vec (range N)))

(def data-al (ArrayList. data-vec))
(def tgt-items (ArrayList. [tgt-item]))


(println :lazy)
(crit/quick-bench
  (remove pred-set data-vec))

(println :lazy-count)
(crit/quick-bench
  (count (remove pred-set data-vec)))

(println :vec)
(crit/quick-bench
  (vec (remove pred-set data-vec)))

(println :ArrayList)
(crit/quick-bench
  (let [changed? (.removeAll data-al tgt-items)]
    data-al))
```

with results:

```
:lazy           Evaluation count : 35819946     time mean :    10.856 ns 
:lazy-count     Evaluation count :     8496     time mean : 69941.171 ns 
:vec            Evaluation count :     9492     time mean : 62965.632 ns 
:ArrayList      Evaluation count :   167490     time mean :  3594.586 ns
```