# Loop through vector of vectors and remove element from vector in Clojure

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am new  to clojure programming and would like some help with some code. I have this vector of vectors like below,

```
(def start-pos [[[:fox :goose :corn :you] [:boat] []]])
```

I would like to loop through the vector and remove an element from one of the internal vectors, e.g. remove ':goose' from start-pos.

I tried the code below but for some reason it doesnt work as intended,

```
(map #(disj (set %) :goose) start-pos)
```

Instead the result is,

```
(#{[:boat] [] [:fox :goose :corn :you]})
```

As you can see from the result, the internal vectors are now a set and yes, the original order is distorted, is there a way of removing the element and not disarrange the original order of the vectors, maybe without converting it to a set first? I choose this conversion to a set first because according to the docs [disj](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/disj) only works for sets.

Add: This post is not similar to [this suggested post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608796/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-vector-in-a-fast-way-in-clojure) as my vector is nested three vectors deep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove elements from a vector in a fast way in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48608796/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-vector-in-a-fast-way-in-clojure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the internal vectors are now a set

That's because the result of `#(disj (set %) :goose)` returns a set.

> original order is distorted

Sets don't preserve insertion order by default, similar to maps with over 8 keys.

> I would like to loop through the vector and **remove** an element from one of the internal vectors, e.g. remove ':goose' from start-pos.

The function you need for removing an element from a collection by predicate is called `remove`, but...

The value you want to remove is actually nested three vectors deep in `start-pos`, so you'd need an additional iteration for each inner vector, and so on if you wanted to remove the keyword `:goose` from every vector recursively. That's an excuse to use `clojure.walk`:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
  (fn [v]
    (if (coll? v)
      (into (empty v) (remove #{:goose}) v)
      v))
  start-pos)
=> [[[:fox :corn :you] [:boat] []]]
```

This walks every value in `start-pos`, removing `:goose` from any collections it finds.

Comment: Thank you for this reply, works. I also realised that nesting the nesting of the vector three times was a mistake and instead what i intended was ```(def start-pos [[:fox :goose :corn :you] [:boat] []])``` . After that my code worked. Thank you for this, will definitely need it in the future

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less flexible approach, that I made more so for my own benefit (learning Clojure)

```
(update-in
  start-pos
  [0 0]
  #(vec (concat
          (subvec % 0 1)
          (subvec % (inc 1)))))
```

It manually navigates in and reconstructs the `:goose` level of keywords to not have `:goose` inside

I think some alternative approaches to this problem include Specter and Zippers

Comment: definitely look into Spectre which makes transformations like this very easy, barely an inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

you could also employ clojure zipper for that:

```
user> (require '[clojure.zip :as z])

user> (loop [curr (z/vector-zip start-pos)]
        (cond (z/end? curr) (z/root curr)
              (= :goose (z/node curr)) (recur (z/remove curr))
              :else (recur (z/next curr))))
;; => [[[:fox :corn :you] [:boat] []]]
```

also, that is quite easy to do with clojure's core functions only:

```
user> (defn remv [pred data]
        (if (vector? data)
          (mapv (partial remv pred) (remove pred data))
          data))
#'user/remv

user> (remv #{:goose} start-pos)
;; => [[[:fox :corn :you] [:boat] []]]
```